# VisJS timeline verticalScroll and horizontalScroll = "true" don't work together in global options

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

For verticalScroll option, the official documentation says that....

Show a vertical scroll on the side of the group list and link it to the scroll event when zoom is not triggered. Notice that defining this option as true will NOT override horizontalScroll. The scroll event will be vertically ignored, but a vertical scrollbar will be visible

But in official demo for visjs and in my project, it doesn't work as expected...

https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/other/verticalScroll.html

If you put verticalScroll and horizontalScroll = "true", verticalScroll is mandatory over all timeline.... and you cannot make horizontalScroll over items...

Any help? any advice?

Thank you,

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I am using vis timeline with reactjs. You must set zoomKey: 'ctrlKey' in order to use scrolling on entire timeline. I tried with different combinations and it works as following:
e.g.

1. horizontalScroll: true, verticalScroll: true, zoomKey: 'ctrlKey' (only Vertical scroller is shown and both scrolling works)
2. horizontalScroll: false, verticalScroll: true, zoomKey: 'ctrlKey' (only vertical scroll works and scroller is shown on the left)
3. horizontalScroll: true, verticalScroll: false, zoomKey: 'ctrlKey' (only horizontal scroll is enabled but no scroller shown, Vertical scrolling is disabled and scroller is hidden as well)

Comment: Thank you Naveed, I'm using visJs with vaadin framework, and I'm using visjs "7.4.9" versión. I have just tried 1 option (the option I want) but still does not work for me. Vertical scrool works, but Horizontal scrool don't. Thank you!